# How to integrate ads into a hybrid application

Tags: javascript, html, telerik, ads, adsense

I have a hybrid applicaion developed with Telerik. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to add banner ads to the app. I've researched everywhere and I cannot find a solution. Does anyone know of an html5 or javascript banner advertising service/API that would be compatible with a Telerik applicaion?
AdSense will not allow their ads to be in an application, as they want devs to use AdMob, which is only compatible for native applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I have never used Telerik. But I used to integrate ads ([inmobi](http://www.inmobi.com/)) into my hybrid app using [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). I found a step-by-step demo for this integration in the link below:
http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/sampleapp/tips/inmobi/

I hope you can use it as a reference. Cheer.

Update: The above link is removed. So, I added the new link for [How to integrate AdMob into Cordova app](https://docs.monaca.io/en/sampleapp/samples/admob/).